# Recognising swipe on List item over TabView

Tags: list, swiftui

I have a List embedded in a TabView. I would like to implement Add/Delete swiping on list rows. Is there a way of making the swipes for the List higher priority in a similar way to using .highPriorityGesture?

The code for the List is below:

```
List
                {
                    ForEach (self.locations ?? [])
                    {
                        location in
                        LocationRowView(location: location)
                            .swipeActions(edge: .leading)
                            {
                                if !locationIsFollowedByUser(location: location)
                                {
                                    Button
                                    {
                                        viewModel.insertNewLocationForUser(vendorId: location.vendor_id, locationId: location.id)
                                    }
                                label:
                                    {
                                        Image(systemName: "goforward.plus")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing)
                        {
                            if locationIsFollowedByUser(location: location)
                            {
                                Button
                                {
                                    viewModel.deleteLocationForUser(vendorId: location.vendor_id, locationId: location.id)
                                }
                            label:
                                {
                                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - so it seems this can't be done.

I worked around it by implementing a Picker control - you don't get the swipe (although I am guessing that could be implemented if desired) - but you do effectively get the 2 pages required.